# create unix timestamp before 1970 on windows using mktime in c

Tags: c, unix-timestamp

Using `c` I'd like to create a unix timestamp for dates before `1970` with visual studio (or preferably both `VS` and `GCC`). The timestamp should be created from date parts. From what I can tell visual studio doesn't support times before `1970`, regardless of whether they are `32` or `64 bit` ...

```
struct tm s_time = {0};
s_time.tm_year = 1940-1900;
s_time.tm_mon = 7 - 1;
s_time.tm_mday = 4;
time_t unix_time = mktime(&s_time);
```

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more about what you're trying to achieve? i.e. Why you need dates before `1970` and how you're going to use them?

Comment: I am pretty sure that on windows you are going to have to give up on CRT based time solutions and have to use native time structs (FILETIME or SYSTEMTIME) and the associated APIs.

Comment: @AndyJ: Please don't format every name or data in the text as code. Code markdown is for **code**, not to emphasise (and there is no need to emphasise names, etc,)

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I'm not sure what you mean by CRT but I think I agree with what you're saying, just being new to working with dates and times in C I wanted to make sure I was understanding the situation correctly that Visual Studio doesn't support something I would think would be fairly standard. That being said I would think you could fake it somehow with native calls ...

Comment: @AndyJ The goal is to have a single number for comparison to other datetimes (that happen before and after 1970). Minute level resolution is sufficient. Obviously one could accomplish comparisons on the structure themselves, I'd just prefer to use single numbers instead. As I type this I realize I could do some bit masking but part of me still wants to know the answer to the exact question asked for general knowledge purposes since I'm surprised there isn't a simple solution that I'm missing.

Comment: Jimbo: CRT=C RunTime

Comment: There is no such thing as Unix timestamp for dates before 1970.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was the following:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define WINDOWS_TICK 10000000
#define SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH 11644473600LL

int64_t date_to_int(SYSTEMTIME *s){

    FILETIME   f;

    SystemTimeToFileTime( s, &f );

    uint64_t temp_result;

    temp_result = (((uint64_t) f.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + f.dwLowDateTime;

    return (int64_t) ((temp_result/ WINDOWS_TICK) - SEC_TO_UNIX_EPOCH);    
}
```